# Running Selenium webdriver scripts in android device (Samasung galaxy tab)-Portrait mode

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver

I have been stuck in an issue while running selenium-java webdriver script in android device -Portrait mode.
    Script is running successfully in landscape mode but when we run the same script in android device keeping device in portrait mode script is failing for few actions 
    like clicking the link, although object locator remains the same. 
    Script is like below,

```
 @Test
  public void testUntitled() throws Exception {
    driver.get("application uRl");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[2]/li[2]/a/div")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("<css selector>")).click();
  }
```

Note: First two stetements are passing in portrait mode , 
  This statements "driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("")).click();" fails in portrait mode by throwing exception like below

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: This WebElement is not visisble and may not be clicked.
Build info: version: &apos;unknown&apos;, revision: &apos;unknown&apos;, time: &apos;unknown&apos;
System info: os.name: &apos;Linux&apos;, os.arch: &apos;armv7l&apos;, os.version: &apos;2.6.36.3&apos;, java.version: &apos;0&apos;
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Command duration or timeout: 322 milliseconds
Build info: version: &apos;2.32.0&apos;, revision: &apos;6c40c18&apos;, time: &apos;2013-04-09 17:22:56&apos;
System info: os.name: &apos;Windows 7&apos;, os.arch: &apos;x86&apos;, os.version: &apos;6.1&apos;, java.version: &apos;1.7.0_40&apos;
Session ID: 1385108177533
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities [{platform=ANDROID, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserName=android, browserConnectionEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=true, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, webdriver.remote.sessionid=1385108177533, takesScreenshot=true, version=13}]
```

Please suggest how this issue can be resolved. Is there any settings to be done for running script in portrait mode?
    Thanks in advance.